# No package R-Rversion available. Error: Nothing to do

Tags: r, linux

Right now I am dealing with installing the R language in one of the linux server distribution but I can't solve this problem

```
No package R-Rversion available.

Error: Nothing to do
```

In this case I was following Oracle R installation instructions, I tried to install it with the 2 versions but it seems to throw the same messsage

Here is some of I made it

```
sudo yum update
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
sudo wget https://public-yum.oracle.com/public-yum-ol7.repo
sudo vi public-yum-ol7.repo
```

Here I changed the enable option to "1" instead of "0"

```
yum install R-Rversion
```

Then I get the error

Someone knows what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `Rversion` with a version number.

Also, you should get the latest version with:

```
yum install R
```